# Python getting module error even though packages are installed( macos)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, f5

I'm following this doc (basic example section) - https://f5-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
as per the doc i have installed f5-sdk using pip3

which pip3
`/usr/local/bin/pip3`

which python3
`/usr/local/bin/python3`

```
 pip3 show -v f5-sdk
Name: f5-sdk
Version: 3.0.21
Summary: F5 Networks Python SDK
Home-page: https://github.com/F5Networks/f5-common-python
Author: F5 Networks
Author-email: f5_common_python@f5.com
License: Apache License, Version 2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
Requires: six, six, f5-icontrol-rest, f5-icontrol-rest
Required-by: 
Metadata-Version: 2.1
Installer: 
Classifiers:
  Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable
  License :: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
  Operating System :: OS Independent
  Programming Language :: Python
  Intended Audience :: System Administrators
Entry-points:
  [pytest11]
  f5sdk_fixtures = f5sdk_plugins.fixtures
```

pip3 install f5-sdk

```
Requirement already satisfied: f5-sdk in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.0.21)
Requirement already satisfied: f5-icontrol-rest>=1.3.13 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from f5-sdk) (1.3.13)
Requirement already satisfied: six<2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from f5-sdk) (1.15.0)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<3,>=2.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from f5-icontrol-rest>=1.3.13->f5-sdk) (2.26.0)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.27,>=1.21.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest>=1.3.13->f5-sdk) (1.26.7)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest>=1.3.13->f5-sdk) (2021.5.30)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<4,>=2.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest>=1.3.13->f5-sdk) (3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer~=2.0.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from requests<3,>=2.5.0->f5-icontrol-rest>=1.3.13->f5-sdk) (2.0.6)
```

when i try to execute script i am getting below error:

python3 f5.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Desktop/python/f5/f5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
  File "Desktop/python/f5/f5.py", line 3, in <module>
    from f5.bigip import ManagementRoot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'f5.bigip'; 'f5' is not a package
```

f5 packages i have under `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`

ls -l | grep f5

```
drwxr-xr-x    9 user  admin     288 Jan 18 13:18 f5
drwxr-xr-x    6 user  admin     192 Jan 18 13:18 f5-sdk-dist
drwxr-xr-x    7 user  admin     224 Jan 18 13:18 f5_icontrol_rest-1.3.13.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x    7 user  admin     224 Jan 18 13:18 f5_sdk-3.0.21.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x    9 root  admin     288 Jan 18 13:20 f5_sdk_python-0.9.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x   14 root  admin     448 Jan 18 13:20 f5sdk
drwxr-xr-x    4 user  admin     128 Jan 18 13:18 f5sdk_plugins
```

any suggestions to fix this error?

Comment: You named your script similar to the package `f5`. Hence, Python tries to import from that script rather than the installed package. Rename your main script to something else, e.g. `main.py`.

Comment: @a_guest worked, thank you